# Access to SSAS from jupyter notebook with python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ssas

I get this error (see picture below) when I try to connect with SSAS database from my jupyter notebook.
[image]

I have tried and tried and googled without success. Maybe I can get a breakthrough from some of you. :)

Thanks for your answers!

Gerard

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant service account "GLOBAL\SSSGTR" access to your SSAS Data Model. Also, in your SSAS Server you need to add this account "GLOBAL\SSSGTR" as an impersonate account with username and password.

```
Goto your SSAS Server-> Database -> Connections -> Right click on connection name -> Properties -> Click on three dots next to 'Impersonation Info" -> Add your service account and password.
```